# MongoDB - querying GridFS by metadata does not return any results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, metadata, gridfs

I am trying to query MongoDB database for a file stored in `GridFS` using metadata in the following way:

```
db['fs'].files.find({'metadata': {'a_field': 'a_value'}})
```

And it does not return any results whereas I can see the file with such a field value exists when I run e.g.:

```
db['fs'].files.find()
```

What is wrong about my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem is solved by changing the nesting of JSON query document from:

```
{'metadata': {'a_field': 'a_value'}}
```

to:

```
{'metadata.a_field': 'a_value'}
```

It is still a mystery to me why the two queries are not equivalent, though.